# What's wrong with my Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I'm new in JavaScript and there is some thing wrong in my codes that I cannot find it! it is driving me crazy.

Ok, this is what I want to do, the user chooses how many poets worked together to write a poem. if the number is one or no number is entered the outcome is the same, that is, the user enters the Last name and the Initial of the poet and the function puts it in desired order, BUT when it is more than one poet (in this example it is 2) I want it to ask for the next poet's Last name and Initial, so I used array, but for some reason the result is just based on the first poet's details only, like this: Lname(0), Iname(0) & ,
 and it doesn't ask for the second poet's LName and initial!
Please let me know what am I doing wrong!

```
 var Initial, LastName, authors;
    var num=1;
    var Iname = [],Lname = [];
    var index = 0;

    num=bookForm.txtNumber.value;
    num=Number(num);
    if (num > 1) { 

        if (num == 2) {
            while (index <= 1){
                Iname[index] = bookForm.txtInitial.value;
                Lname[index] = bookForm.txtLastName.value;
                bookForm.txtInitial.value="";
                bookForm.txtLastName.value="";
                bookForm.txtInitial.focus();
                index = index + 1;
            }
            authors = Lname[0]+", "+Iname[0]+" & "+Lname[1]+", "+Iname[1]+" "
        }
    }
    else {
    Initial = bookForm.txtInitial.value+" "
    LastName = bookForm.txtLastName.value+", ";
    authors = LastName+Initial;
    }
```

Comment: Focusing on the element doesn't make the script wait for the user to enter a new value.

Comment: A script can't stop and wait for the user to fill in a form field. You have to return from your function and use an event listener to do something when he fills in the form.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks you just opened a door to a whole new chapter for me...

Comment: Instead of reusing the same input field, make a table of inputs, so the user can enter them all at once.

Comment: Yep that's better idea. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

It looks, you reinitialize value of field  with

`bookForm.txtInitial.value="";
 bookForm.txtLastName.value="";`

when you pass for the second time in your loop, the value is empty.

Comment: This is technically true, but has nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: ok, I think I understand you want something like  "Waiting I put the value before continue the loop".  That's it?  Because you cannot do this like this the method "focus()" only put the focus to the component but dont wait any return

Comment: @ChristofHullaert Yes like waitng for the user to enter the next value

Comment: Maybe you can do a button add poet instead of choose number of poet at start and each time the button is pressed you add the poet at the end of your array.

Comment: with pleasure, maybe you can vote for the answer.  This way other people will be helped.